# Updating my table with the new encrypted values

Tags: java

My program take two variables( key and text ) and with some algorithms that i did to encrypt these two variables. But i tried to apply that program on such field(job_name in job table)to encrypt its values i faced a problem.
This is my program :

```
     public class  dbconnection {
     java.sql.Connection con;
     java.sql.Statement st;
     ResultSet rs;

     public   EncBean getConnection()throws SQLException{

    EncBean encBean1 = new EncBean(); 
    String v_url= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.172:1522:orcl2";
    String v_username= "scott";
    String v_password = "tiger";

       try
            {
   DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
   //  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(v_url,v_username,v_password); 
        System.out.println ("Connection to Oracle database  was     Established");
            }

        catch ( SQLException e) 
        {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
       return encBean1;
     }
      public  EncBean selectRows()

        {
         EncBean encBean2 = new EncBean(); 
         try
            {

            String SQLselect="select JOB_NAME from job";
            st=con.createStatement();
            rs=st.executeQuery(SQLselect);

    while (rs.next()) {

            encBean2.setName(rs.getString("JOB_NAME"));
                        }   

            }
    catch ( Exception ex ) 
        {
       ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    return encBean2;}

       public  void updateRows(String updatedname){            
   try
    {

  String sql_statment = "UPDATE job SET job_name ='"+updatedname+"'";
  System.out.println(sql_statment);
   PreparedStatement updatequery = con.prepareStatement(sql_statment);
   ResultSet rs = updatequery.executeQuery();
   int records = rs.getInt(1);
   for (int i=0; i<=records; i++) {
   updatequery.setString(2,"job_name"+i);
   } 
   updatequery.execute();
   con.commit();
    System.out.println("An existing user was updated successfully!");
  }
  catch(SQLException err){
  System.out.println(err.getMessage());
   } }}
```

In  main i call this method to firstly retrive data,encrypt it      and lastly update data in table job

```
 public class mainenc {    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
 dbconnection dbcon = new dbconnection();
 EncBean encbeancon=  dbcon.getConnection();     
 EncBean encBean5 = dbcon.selectRows(); 
 enc concatinputs = new enc();    
 EncBean encBeanconcat = concatinputs.funconcat(encBean5.getName());
 EncBean encBean4 =   concatinputs.inputencryption(encBeanconcat.getConcatenatedData());
  String vReserverbin= encBean4.getReversedBinary();
 String  ascistring=     concatinputs.convertBinaryStringToString(vReserverbin);
 System.out.println(ascistring);   
  dbcon.updateRows(ascistring);
```

the output is: 
  32313050"2#3&3'2"3&2&3$1'2$2&250 // the encrypted value
  UPDATE job SET job_name ='32313050"2#3&3'2"3&2&3$1'2$2&250'
  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
  Hello World!
  Process completed.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clear idea about your `updateRows` method in `dbconnection` class. I think you don't have a proper idea about `execute()` and `executeQuery()` methods.

- boolean execute(String SQL) :-  It returns a boolean value true if a
  ResultSet object can be retrieved; otherwise, it returns false. We
  can use this method to execute SQL DDL statements.
- ResultSet executeQuery(String SQL) :- It returns a ResultSet object.
  We can use this method when we want to execute SELECT queries in db.

So in this case I assume that you are going to perform an update inside the `updateRows` method. So its useless to use  `ResultSet rs = updatequery.executeQuery();` once you are going to perform an update. And it also gives you an Error.`(java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().)`.You can use `ps.execute();` to make it success.
 **It's good practice to perform update like below:**

```
PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement("UPDATE job SET job_name =? WHERE job_id=?");
          ps.setString(1, "Sam");
          ps.setInt(2, 2);
          ps.execute();
```

**String concatenation to create queries may occur performance and as well as security issues too.**

Comment: Very thanks for you Madushan Perera for your reply , I want to tell you that  the key is not in data base but i enter it at runtime where the key is conctenated with the field name(job_name) and they are encrypted by some dependant functions . i want to update my table by these  encrypted values in the field. how can i do that? suggest for me.